# Let $f(X)=\|X\|$ and $g(X)=\|X\|^2$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f(X)=\|X\|$ and $g(X)=\|X\|^2$, $X\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Give an example of points $X$ and $Y$ at distance one unit, such that.

$a)$ $|g(Y) - g(X)|> 10^{60}$

$b)$ Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous

$c)$ Show that $g$ is not uniformly continuous

For the first clause we could consider the numbers $10^{60}$ and $10^{60}+1$. For $b)$ it is seen that it is a uniformly continuous function, but I don't know how to start with my formal proof.

Comment: I don't follow your meaning when you write "For the first clause we could consider the numbers $10^{60}$ and $10^{60}+1$."  You are asked to find $X,Y \in \Bbb{R}^n$ with $||X|| = ||Y|| = 1$ such that $| \, ||Y||^2 - ||X||^2 \, | > 10^{60}$.  These $X$ and $Y$ aren't numbers; they're vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (b) the magic words are "triangle inequality". For (c), your example (I assume it really means vectors $(10^{60}, 0, \dotsc, 0)$ and $(10^{60}+1, 0, \dotsc, 0))$ shows you the way. All you need to show is that the function $f(x) = x^2$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: As $|x-y|\geq  ||x|-|y||=|f(x)-f(y)|$, is it enough to take $\varepsilon = \delta $? Then $f$ is uniformly continuous...

Comment: To prove $g$, we have that for all $\delta$, and $\varepsilon = 1$, $y=x+\frac{\delta}{2}$ we would have a contradiction, since we can choose x large, right?

Comment: @Gabriela yes, correct.